How to implement partially wildcard routes in Angular 17
I am supposed to load a common component for all the following links
localhost:4200/{TENANT1}/Dashboard/Index
localhost:4200/{Tenant2}/Dashboard/Index
I am trying the following wildcard routing logic but it's not working out.
  {
    path: '**',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'Dashboard/Index', component: DashboardComponent
      },
    ],
  },

I also tried the following, which is also not working out
  { path: '**/Dashboard/Index', pathMatch: 'full', component: DashboardComponent },


Try setting tenant as a route parameter
{
    path: ':tenant',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'Dashboard/Index', component: DashboardComponent
      },
    ],
  

Wildcard matches the full route I think, not just the route segment
